# Scilab: where is optim function source file situated

Tags: function, optimization, scilab

I had some problems with understanding how function *loadwave(...)* exactly works. So i found a file with its description here: /usr/share/scilab/modules/sound/macros/loadwave.sci using *find -name  ...* command.

Now i don't understand how *optim(...)* function works and so i also want to find its source file but i can't (i tried to use combinations of *find* and *grep* again). There are some demo files with examples of optim usage in /usr/share/scilab/modules/optimization/demos/optim directory but i still can not find any source code of *optim(...)* itself that as i understand should look somehow as follows:

*function [...]=optim(...)*

*...*

*end function;*

Could you give me a tip, please?

**Update:**
for now I only managed to find this in file
/usr/share/scilab/modules/optimization/sci_gateway/optimization_gateway.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE GATEWAY SYSTEM "../../functions/xml/gateway.dtd">
<GATEWAY name="optimization">
<!-- =================== -->
<!--
 Scilab
 Interface description. In this file, we define the list of the function which
 will be available into Scilab and the link to the "native" function.

 gatewayId is the position in the hashtable 'Interfaces' defined in the
 file SCI/modules/core/src/c/callinterf.h

 primitiveId is the position in the hashtable '<module>Table Tab[]' defined
 in the file modules/<module>/sci_gateway/c/gw_<module>.c

 primitiveName is the name of the Scilab function
 ===================
 Don't touch if you do not know what you are doing
-->
<!-- =================== -->

<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="1" primitiveName="optim" />
<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="2" primitiveName="semidef" />
<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="3" primitiveName="fsolve" />
<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="4" primitiveName="lsqrsolve" />
<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="5" primitiveName="qld" />
<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="6" primitiveName="qp_solve" />
<PRIMITIVE gatewayId="11" primitiveId="7" primitiveName="readmps" />
</GATEWAY>
```

So in the git repo of scilab the link to which has been kindly given to me by **user1149326** below i have found the file scilab/modules/optimization/sci_gateway/c/sci_optim.c (http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=blob;f=scilab/modules/optimization/sci_gateway/c/sci_optim.c;h=608f7dabe822fc6cfecb456e847f3b7373014322;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 2):

You can check out all Scilab sources at [their git repository](http://gitweb.scilab.org). More specifically all `optim` sources are in [the optimization module](http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=tree;f=scilab/modules/optimization;hb=HEAD). See the `src` and `macro` folder. You can read about how the module is organized on [their wiki](http://wiki.scilab.org/Scilab%20Module%20Architecture).

I think the sources are too complex to give you insight in how `optim` works. Instead of looking at the sources, I would recommend [a document by Scilab about the kinds of optimization](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scilab.org%2Fcontent%2Fdownload%2F250%2F1714%2Ffile%2Foptimization_in_scilab.pdf) , that may also give the information you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the links. But, unfortunately, i still can't find optim definition there. Maybe, i understand something wrong.

Comment: My answer was a little bit incomplete, so I updated it

Comment: Thank you for your help, i  will try to explore the document. I hope it will help.

Comment: Sorry, i can't accept your answer because it's not completely what i'm searching for. But when i have enough reputation i will not forget to vote your answer because it has given me a lot of useful info.

Comment: No problem, good luck! If you find out an answer don't hesitate to answer your own question.